# Generate matrix with value flags

Tags: r

I do have a solution for the following problem but it's quite ugly and it can most likely be done in a much shorter way. Would be great to get your help.

My input looks like this:

```
C1     C2 
A      B     
B      D    
D      C 
A      D
```

and my output should look like this:

```
A B C D
1 1 0 0
0 1 0 1
0 0 1 1  
1 0 0 1
```

My current solution is:

```
index <- unique(unlist(input[,1:2]))
output <- matrix(0,nrows=dim(input),ncols=length(index))
for(i in 1:dim(input)) {
    output[i, input[i,]$C1] <- 1
    output[i, input[i,]$C2] <- 1
}
```

Of course 4-5 lines is actually fine - but even as an R beginner this doesn't feel right to use a *for* loop. Besides that my actual data has much more than two columns, therefore this doesn't look nice in the end. How would I do that in a smarter way?

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
library(plyr)
all.levels <- sort(levels(unlist(input)))
adply(input, 1, function(x)table(factor(unlist(x), all.levels)))
#   C1 C2 A B C D
# 1  A  B 1 1 0 0
# 2  B  D 0 1 0 1
# 3  D  C 0 0 1 1
# 4  A  D 1 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Base solution:

```
test <- data.frame( C1=c("A","B","D","A"),
                C2=c("B","D","C","D"),
                stringsAsFactors=FALSE
            )

uniqnames <- sort(unique(unlist(test[,1:2])))
idcols <- (t(apply(test, 1 , '%in%', x = uniqnames)) + 0) #thanks mnel!
colnames(idcols) <- uniqnames

result <- cbind(
    test,
    idcols
    )
```

Final dataset:

```
> result
  C1 C2 A B C D
1  A  B 1 1 0 0
2  B  D 0 1 0 1
3  D  C 0 0 1 1
4  A  D 1 0 0 1
```

Comment: @mnel - nice pickup, will edit the answer to this line as it is simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this with `cast` from the `reshape` package. <s>I can't test the code right now (my R version is too old, currently recompiling it)</s>

```
cast(cbind(input, 1), C1 ~ C2, sum, add.missing=T)
```

this will actually count the number of times each pair appears, to change this behaviour replace `sum` with a constant function (there's probably a prettier way, not requiring the cbind/sum, but my R is quite rusty).

EDIT: Added add.missing